# Copy select value data form one form to another without button in form1

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi I have problems to figure out how to copy select value data from one form to another form. I need a copy javascript for this I guess.

Form1

```
      <form id="form1" name="form1">
      <input type="checkbox" name="email'.$emailCount++.'" value="'.email.'"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="name'.$nameCount++.'" value="'.$id.'"/>
      </form>
```

Form2

```
      <form id="form2"  method="POST" action="script/do-something.php" name="form2">
      <label for="name">Add Selected</label>
      <select name="list" id="list" class="form-text">
      <option value="">Add To List</option>
      <option value="All">All</option>
      <option value="All">Blog</option>
      <option value="All">Dj</option>
      </select>
      <input type="hidden" name="name'.$nameCount++.'" value="'.$id.'"/>
      <input type="button" name="new_address" id="clicky3" value="Add Selected">
      </form>
```

Comment: Mention clearly, what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I just want to copy this value from form 1 to form 2 using a javascript without button on form1 <input type="hidden" name="name'.$nameCount++.'" value="'.$id.'"/>

Comment: if your not going to trigger the values moving across with a button what are you going to use as a trigger?

Comment: You mean to say you want to post the value of <input type="hidden" name="name'.$nameCount++.'" value="'.$id.'"/>  of form1 as well when you submit the form2, right?

Comment: The thing is I have a popup form on form2 and I don't want to have the select php while loop in that form I want that in form1

Comment: You got me more confused. Explain it clearly.

Comment: me too @KCP i thought i had it till i noticed both name fields are hidden but there is still a label for  a input with the name of name on form 2 and well i just don't know

Comment: Yes KCP that is exactly what Im trying to do post the value of <input type="hidden" name="name'.$nameCount++.'" value="'.$id.'"/> of form1 as well when you submit the form2 [see image here...](http://www.promotionfordjs.com/images/pic1.png)